# Second Largest Number

Tags: python, loops, while-loop

How do I write a program that takes an indefinite amount of numbers as input and outputs the next
largest number to the screen after the user is finished entering numbers and would like to
exit.

An example of user interaction with the program is shown below:

```
Please enter a positive number (type -1 to exit): 99
Please enter a positive number (type -1 to exit): 66
Please enter a positive number (type -1 to exit): 5
Please enter a positive number (type -1 to exit): 23
Please enter a positive number (type -1 to exit): 46
Please enter a positive number (type -1 to exit): 326
Please enter a positive number (type -1 to exit): 661
Please enter a positive number (type -1 to exit): -3
The second largest number entered is: 661
```

Comment: If 661 is the second largest, what's the largest?

Comment: save input to list, sort the list, return the second one

Comment: We're happy to help you with your homework, but you need to make a start yourself and post a code attempt, clearly explaining where you're stuck.

Comment: [How to ask about homework](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/334822/how-do-i-ask-and-answer-homework-questions)

Answer (score 1):

This is an example for Python2.x,if you're using Python3 try to use `input` rather than `raw_input`.My way is to take the input as string and use `try/catch` to convert it to integer,and then store them to a list.

You can use `max` method to get the largest value and remove it,so that next time when you use `max` you will get the second largest number.

```
input_list=[]
while True:
    string=raw_input("Please enter a positive number (type -1 to exit)")
    try:
        num=int(string.strip())
        if num!=-1:
            input_list.append(num)
        else:
            largest=max(input_list)
            input_list.remove(largest)
            print "The largest value is {0}".format(largest)
            sec_largest=max(input_list)
            input_list.remove(sec_largest)
            print "The second largest value is {0}".format(sec_largest)
            break
    except Exception as e:
        print "can not convert string to int"
```

Also you can sort the list if it is not very large,otherwise it might take some time,and then pop the largest number.

Another way,if you just want the second largest number,you can compare the input with the last input number,it will take less memory.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Should we really be outright just code dumping people's homework like this? I can't see how this is a learning exercise for anyone that gets problems solved for them when they fail to even attempt their assignment or provide us with any attempted code. Good on you for solving their problem, but rather than this helping them, it's hurting them in the long-run. Quoting you, "What hurts more, the pain of hard work, or the pain of regret?" -- they don't learn the pain of any hard work, and only regret never learning.

Comment: @downshift You are absolutely right,SO is not a coding service,we always downvote and leave a comment,I know this is not the best way,we want to the OP try to code himself,so I try to give an example with explanation,and another two ways without code.It might be helpful.It depends on the OP.

Comment: I don't subscribe to the downvote principle, I'll leave that to others who wish to downvote someone's good intentions, instead I just wanted to note the OP's blatant lack of effort. Otherwise, no worries. Cheers.